# Hibernate how to validation inner class properties

Tags: hibernate, validation, inner-classes

Here's my code, I have marked with comments the parts that doesn't work

```
@Data
public class PopularTravelProductsDTO extends MobileRequest {

    @NotNull  //work
    private PopularTravelProductsInfo popularTravelProductsInfo;

    @Data
    public class PopularTravelProductsInfo {

        @NotNull //doesn't work
        private Integer pageNum;

        @NotNull //doesn't work
        private Integer size;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does'nt work"? What are you expacting? What does this decorator do?

Answer (score 0):

use @Valid annotation

```
@Data
public class PopularTravelProductsDTO extends MobileRequest {

    @NotNull  
    @Valid
    private PopularTravelProductsInfo popularTravelProductsInfo;

    @Data
    public class PopularTravelProductsInfo {

        @NotNull 
        private Integer pageNum;

        @NotNull 
        private Integer size;
    }
}
```